# Framebuffer in Libgdx, using glclearcolor() clears whole screen

Tags: opengl, libgdx, framebuffer

[image: desired output][image: acutal output]I'm using `glClearColor` inside `begin()` and `end()` in `framebuffer`,
but it is clearing the whole screen color, Am I doing something wrong?

```
public class FrameBufferTest implements ApplicationListener{

    OrthographicCamera camera;
    SpriteBatch batcher;
    FrameBuffer fbo;
    Texture tex;
    @Override
    public void create() {
        batcher = new SpriteBatch();

        camera = new OrthographicCamera(800, 480);
        camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth/2f, camera.viewportHeight/2f, 0);

        fbo = new FrameBuffer(Format.RGBA8888, 100, 100,false);

        camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth/2f, camera.viewportHeight/2f, 0);
        tex = new Texture("data/bg.png");
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        GL20 gl = Gdx.graphics.getGL20();
        gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glClearColor(0.5f,0.5f,0.5f,0.5f); // grey color

        camera.update();
        batcher.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

        batcher.enableBlending();
        batcher.begin();
            batcher.draw(tex, 0, 0, 256, 256);
        batcher.end();

        fbo.begin();
            gl.glClearColor(1f,0,0,1f);
            gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        fbo.end();

        batcher.begin();
            batcher.draw(fbo.getColorBufferTexture(), 512, 0, 100, 100);
        batcher.end();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swap these two lines at the beginning of your render method:

```
gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
gl.glClearColor(0.5f,0.5f,0.5f,0.5f); // grey color
```

In the order you have them, it is clearing the color using the most recently set clear color, which is the red that you set farther down in your render method (since this is a loop).

Comment: is there any way I can use color the framebuffer, without using mesh or shape_renderer.

Comment: Isn't that what you've already done? You made the frame buffer red.